# Why we need the constructor while injecting service into component in Angular2

Tags: angular, service

I am following https://angular.io for learning Angular2. While going through "Service" chapter, I am not able to understand why we need the following code after importing the service in component:-

```
constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }
```

Why we can't use HeroService directly in Component as we are doing in case of Hero field as below:

```
export class AppComponent {
 title = 'Tour of Heroes';
 selectedHero: Hero;
 heroes : Hero[];

 onSelect(hero: Hero): void{
  this.selectedHero = hero;
 }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing doesn't do much except making names known to the current code file, but that by itself doesn't add any feature to your application.

For a service class you need an instance. You can create it with `new MyService()`. But if it has dependencies, like `Http`, you need to use `new MyService(new Http()`. Because `Http` itself has many dependencies, this gets out of hand very fast.

With

```
constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }
```

you tell Angulars DI to pass a `HeroService` instance from the next provide it finds, and also to pass all dependency it discovers from `HeroService`s `constructor` parameters, and from the constructor parameters of these parameters until everything that is required is resolved.

You can read more about the general principle in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control

Answer (score 1):

Services ALWAYS need to be called inside the constructor to be able to use them in the component. Think of the constructor as something that collects and prepares every single service that your component will use before the component is even loaded.

Comment: How Angular verifies whether imported reference is a service or component.

Comment: Through the @Injectable decorator:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#injectable

Answer (score 1):

`Hero` is just an object, so you can use it directly

```
const hero = new Hero() // works fine
```

With `HeroService` you are utilizing Dependency Injection. And that's how DI works with Angular, by declaring services in the constructor. You can have a service that doesn't use DI, let's say

```
class NoDIService() {
  add(x, y) { return x + y; }
}
```

and you can use it without DI, just like you did with `Hero`:

```
const myService = new NoDIService();
```

but when you need to use angular's built-in features, you will use Dependency Injection and register your services with DI...